# How can i add or & and Criteria clauses with in a single Query Object Mongodb Spring data

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I want to add or & and clauses to my query object at the same time but i am keep getting te below error

Due to limitations of the com.mongodb.BasicDBObject, you can't add a second 'null' criteria?

For example

```
query.addCriteria(new Criteria().orOperator(Some Critera);


 query.addCriteria(new Criteria().andOperator(Some Critera);
```

Can anyone help me out on this?

**Detail:**

Actually i am try to parse the following json and building dynamic query based on that parsed json

```
{
  "query":{

    "where":[{

              "or":[
              {
                 "fieldName":"address1","fieldValue":"Dummy address1",

                 "operator":"equal"
              }

            ],
            "and":[{
                  "fieldName":"version","fieldValue":"1",

                 "operator":"equal"

             }]
           }
        ]
   }
}
```

So you can suggest me other ways to parse that json into Mongodb query using mongoTemplate spring data

here is my parsing code

```
if(null != eventSearch.getQuery())
        {

            if(null != eventSearch.getQuery().getWhere() && eventSearch.getQuery().getWhere().size() > 0)
            {

                for (Where whereClause : eventSearch.getQuery().getWhere()) {

                      if(null != whereClause.getOr() && whereClause.getOr().size() > 0){

                          List<org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria> orCriterias = new ArrayList<org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria>(whereClause.getOr().size());

                          for (Field field: whereClause.getOr()) {

                              if(field.getOperator().equalsIgnoreCase(QueryOperator.IS))
                              {
                                orCriterias.add(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria.where(field.getFieldName()).is(field.getFieldValue()));

                              }else if(field.getOperator().equalsIgnoreCase(QueryOperator.LT)){

                                orCriterias.add(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria.where(field.getFieldName()).lt(field.getFieldValue()));
                              } 
                              else if(field.getOperator().equalsIgnoreCase(QueryOperator.GT)){

                                  orCriterias.add(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria.where(field.getFieldName()).gt(field.getFieldValue()));
                              } 
                              else if(field.getOperator().equalsIgnoreCase(QueryOperator.LTE)){

                                  orCriterias.add(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria.where(field.getFieldName()).lte(field.getFieldValue()));
                               }
                              else if(field.getOperator().equalsIgnoreCase(QueryOperator.GTE)){

                                  orCriterias.add(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria.where(field.getFieldName()).gte(field.getFieldValue()));
                               }
                          } 

                          query.addCriteria(new org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria().orOperator(orCriterias.toArray(new org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria[whereClause.getOr().size()])));
                      }

                      if(null != whereClause.getAnd() && whereClause.getAnd().size() > 0){

                          List<org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria> andCriterias = new ArrayList<org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria>(whereClause.getAnd().size());

                          for (Field field: whereClause.getAnd()) {

                              if(field.getOperator().equalsIgnoreCase(QueryOperator.IS))
                              {
                                  andCriterias.add(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria.where(field.getFieldName()).is(field.getFieldValue()));

                              }else if(field.getOperator().equalsIgnoreCase(QueryOperator.LT)){

                                  andCriterias.add(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria.where(field.getFieldName()).lt(field.getFieldValue()));
                              } 
                              else if(field.getOperator().equalsIgnoreCase(QueryOperator.GT)){

                                  andCriterias.add(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria.where(field.getFieldName()).gt(field.getFieldValue()));
                              } 
                              else if(field.getOperator().equalsIgnoreCase(QueryOperator.LTE)){

                                  andCriterias.add(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria.where(field.getFieldName()).lte(field.getFieldValue()));
                               }
                              else if(field.getOperator().equalsIgnoreCase(QueryOperator.GTE)){

                                  andCriterias.add(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria.where(field.getFieldName()).gte(field.getFieldValue()));
                               }
                          } 
                          //Getting exception at this line
                          query.addCriteria(new org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria().andOperator(andCriterias.toArray(new org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria[whereClause.getAnd().size()])));
                      }
}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is too loog, I replaced `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria` with `Criteria` temporarily.

```
    // added
    Query query = new Query();

    if(null != eventSearch.getQuery())
    {

        if(null != eventSearch.getQuery().getWhere() && eventSearch.getQuery().getWhere().size() > 0)
        {
            // added
            List<Criteria> wheres = new ArrayList<>();

            for (Where whereClause : eventSearch.getQuery().getWhere()) {

                // added
                Criteria where = new Criteria();

                  if(null != whereClause.getOr() && whereClause.getOr().size() > 0){

                      List<Criteria> orCriterias = new ArrayList<Criteria>(whereClause.getOr().size());

                      for (Field field: whereClause.getOr()) {

                          if(field.getOperator().equalsIgnoreCase(QueryOperator.IS))
                          {
                            orCriterias.add(Criteria.where(field.getFieldName()).is(field.getFieldValue()));

                          }else if(field.getOperator().equalsIgnoreCase(QueryOperator.LT)){

                            orCriterias.add(Criteria.where(field.getFieldName()).lt(field.getFieldValue()));
                          } 
                          else if(field.getOperator().equalsIgnoreCase(QueryOperator.GT)){

                              orCriterias.add(Criteria.where(field.getFieldName()).gt(field.getFieldValue()));
                          } 
                          else if(field.getOperator().equalsIgnoreCase(QueryOperator.LTE)){

                              orCriterias.add(Criteria.where(field.getFieldName()).lte(field.getFieldValue()));
                           }
                          else if(field.getOperator().equalsIgnoreCase(QueryOperator.GTE)){

                              orCriterias.add(Criteria.where(field.getFieldName()).gte(field.getFieldValue()));
                           }
                      } 

                      // comment out
                      // query.addCriteria(new Criteria().orOperator(orCriterias.toArray(new Criteria[whereClause.getOr().size()])));

                      // replaced with
                      if (orCriterias.size() > 0) {
                          where.orOperator(orCriterias.toArray(new Criteria[0]));
                      }
                  }

                  if(null != whereClause.getAnd() && whereClause.getAnd().size() > 0){

                      List<Criteria> andCriterias = new ArrayList<Criteria>(whereClause.getAnd().size());

                      for (Field field: whereClause.getAnd()) {

                          if(field.getOperator().equalsIgnoreCase(QueryOperator.IS))
                          {
                              andCriterias.add(Criteria.where(field.getFieldName()).is(field.getFieldValue()));

                          }else if(field.getOperator().equalsIgnoreCase(QueryOperator.LT)){

                              andCriterias.add(Criteria.where(field.getFieldName()).lt(field.getFieldValue()));
                          } 
                          else if(field.getOperator().equalsIgnoreCase(QueryOperator.GT)){

                              andCriterias.add(Criteria.where(field.getFieldName()).gt(field.getFieldValue()));
                          } 
                          else if(field.getOperator().equalsIgnoreCase(QueryOperator.LTE)){

                              andCriterias.add(Criteria.where(field.getFieldName()).lte(field.getFieldValue()));
                           }
                          else if(field.getOperator().equalsIgnoreCase(QueryOperator.GTE)){

                              andCriterias.add(Criteria.where(field.getFieldName()).gte(field.getFieldValue()));
                           }
                      } 

                      // comment out
                      // //Getting exception at this line
                      // query.addCriteria(new Criteria().andOperator(andCriterias.toArray(new Criteria[whereClause.getAnd().size()])));

                      // replaced with
                      if (andCriterias.size() > 0) {
                          where.andOperator(andCriterias.toArray(new Criteria[0]));
                      }

                  }

                  // added
                  wheres.add(where);
                }
                // added
                if (wheres.size() > 0) {
                    query.addCriteria(new Criteria().andOperator(wheres.toArray(new Criteria[0])));
                }
            }
    }
```

**If your operators only includes** `== != < <= > >=`, you may try to shorten the codes by changing the JSON directly or indirectly, like this:

```
{
  "query":{

    "where":[{

              "or":[
              {
                 "fieldName":"address1","fieldValue":"Dummy address1",

                 "operator":"equal"
              },
              {
                 "fieldName":"address1","fieldValue":"Dummy address2",

                 "operator":"$gt" // added: greater than
              },
              {
                 "fieldName":"address1","fieldValue":"Dummy address3",

                 "operator":"$ne" // added: not equal
              }

            ],
            "and":[{
                  "fieldName":"version","fieldValue":"1",

                 "operator":"equal"

             }]
           }
        ]
   }
}
```

Then, partial codes can be written like this:

```
  for (Field field: whereClause.getAnd()) {

      if(field.getOperator().equalsIgnoreCase(QueryOperator.IS))
      {
          andCriterias.add(Criteria.where(field.getFieldName()).is(field.getFieldValue()));

      } else {
          andCriterias.add(Criteria.where(field.getOperator()).is(new BasicDBObject(field.getFieldName(), field.getFieldValue())));
      }
  }
```

`whereClause.getOr()` is similar to `whereClause.getAnd()`, then you can combine them in a cycle to shorten codes if you want.

Comment: @Ramzan Zafar, It's nice that helps you. I've added something maybe it can help to optimize codes.

Answer (score 1):

I can't realy help you with the parsing code but you can build the query from the inner level by using

```
DBObject conditions = new BasicDBObject("field1",val1).append("field2",val2)...;
```

and then chaining them together with

```
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$or",conditions);
```

and

```
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$and",conditions);
```